# liferay 7.2 service-builder error.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/orm/ArgumentsResolver when deploying the service

Tags: java, deployment, liferay, noclassdeffounderror, liferay-service-builder

I am working  on a portal project using Liferay 7.2
and I have created a service by using a service-builder template, I followed the tutorial step by step.
but I am getting the following error when I deploy the service.

*2021-07-28 20:24:59.092 ERROR [pipe-start 2245][RatingPersistenceImpl:93] bundle com.arabiait.mawareeth.service:1.0.0 (2245)[com.arabiait.mawareeth.service.persistence.impl.RatingPersistenceImpl(5523)] : The activate method has thrown an exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/orm/ArgumentsResolver
at com.arabiait.mawareeth.service.persistence.impl.RatingPersistenceImpl.activate(RatingPersistenceImpl.java:1997)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)*

=======================================================================

there is a nested static class that implements this ArgumentResolver interface already generated in the RatingPersistenceImpl.java as follows:

```
private static class RatingModelArgumentsResolver
        implements ArgumentsResolver {
}
```

==========================================================================
the line that throws the exception is inside the RatingPersistenceImpl.java as follows:

```
_argumentsResolverServiceRegistration = _bundleContext.registerService(
            ArgumentsResolver.class, new RatingModelArgumentsResolver(),
            MapUtil.singletonDictionary(
                "model.class.name", Rating.class.getName()));
```

## service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 7.3.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_7_3_0.dtd">

<service-builder dependency-injector="ds" package-path="com.arabiait.mawareeth">
    <namespace>MW</namespace>
    <!--<entity data-source="sampleDataSource" local-service="true" name="Foo" remote-service="false" session-factory="sampleSessionFactory" table="foo" tx-manager="sampleTransactionManager uuid="true"">-->
    <entity local-service="true" name="Rating" remote-service="true" uuid="true">

        <!-- PK fields -->

        <column name="ratingId" primary="true" type="long" />

        <!-- Group instance -->

        <column name="groupId" type="long" />

        <!-- Audit fields -->

        <column name="companyId" type="long" />
        <column name="userId" type="long" />
        <column name="userName" type="String" />
        <column name="createDate" type="Date" />
        <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />

        <!-- Other fields -->

        <!-- Order -->
        <column name="name" type="String"></column>
        <column name="comment" type="String"></column>
        <column name="rate" type="int"></column>
        <column name="pageName" type="String"></column>

        

        <!-- References -->

        <reference entity="AssetEntry" package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" />
        <reference entity="AssetTag" package-path="com.liferay.portlet.asset" />
    </entity>
</service-builder>
```

If someone can help me, I will be so grateful as I am overwhelmed by this issue for 3 days till now.

Comment: Most likely you're building for a different version than you're deploying to. Assuming you're building with Liferay Workspace, make sure that your target platform version (in gradle.properties) is set to the version you're building for and that it's configured for the correct bundle.

Comment: yes exactly... I found that the target platform of the workspace is different than the platform that we deploy on it.
but I have a different problem now.. I don't have any errors in the services but when I integrate it with the portlet .. the portlet disappeared from the portal page and give this error
This portlet could not be found. Please redeploy it or remove it from the page
but the console does not have any error